# AsyncResult(task_id) returns "PENDING" state even after the task started

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

In the project, I try to poll task.state of a long running task and update its running status. It worked in the development, but it won't work when I move the project on production server. I kept getting 'PENDING' even I can see the task started on flower. However, I can still get the results updated when the task finished, which when task.state == 'SUCCESS'. I use python 2.6, Django 1.6 and Celery 3.1 in the production, result backend AMQP.

```
@csrf_exempt
def poll_state(request):
    data = 'Fail'

    if request.is_ajax():
            if 'task_id' in request.POST.keys() and request.POST['task_id']:
                    task_id = request.POST['task_id']
                    email = request.POST['email']
                    task = AsyncResult(task_id)
                    print "task.state=", task.state
                    if task.state == 'STARTED':
                            task_state = 'Running'
                            data = 'Running'
                            #data = 'Running'
                    elif task.state == 'PENDING' or task.state == 'RETRY':
                            task_state = 'Waiting'
                            data = 'Pending'
                    elif task.state == 'SUCCESS':
                            task_state = 'Finished'
                            if task.result:
                                    data = task.result
                            else:
                                    data = 'None'

                    else:
                            task_state = task.state
                            data = 'Error'
                            print 'data status =', task_state
            else:
                    task_state = task.state
                    data = 'Error'
    else:
            task_state = task.state
            data = "Error"

    json_data = json.dumps({'task_state':task_state, 'task_data':data})

 return HttpResponse(json_data, mimetype='application/json')
```

on another note, flower always show the workers' status offline, but tasks status were correct. When using celery events 3.1.12 (Cipater), it shows correct worker status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably related to [CELERY_TRACK_STARTED](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-track-started) setting. Quoting the docs:

> CELERY_TRACK_STARTED
>
> If True the task will report its status as
>   “started” when the task is executed by a worker. The default value is
>   False as the normal behaviour is to not report that level of
>   granularity. Tasks are either pending, finished, or waiting to be
>   retried. Having a “started” state can be useful for when there are
>   long running tasks and there is a need to report which task is
>   currently running.

Maybe you have `CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True` in your development settings, but not in production ?

Comment: I had 'CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True' in my settings.py and I set celeryconfig.py with os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings'). The problem is that AsyncResult(task_id).state always return 'PENDING' status so my template cannot update to 'STARTED' when the task started. But both flower and celery events monitor showed task started correctly. Very confused.

Comment: Can you run on the terminal where your prodution is running `celery inspect conf --app your_app_name` just to check if the setting `CELERY_TRACK_STARTED` were well loaded?

Comment: That's the problem! app.conf is not updated until I set it explicitly in tasks.py. I guess os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings') has not been working. I am still confused about why this happened.

Answer (score 11):

For Celery 4.1.0 and Django 1.11.7 this is what you need in the config.py file:

Correct:

```
task_track_started = True
```

Also Correct:

```
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
```

WRONG!:

```
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
```

Just took me 2 hours to figure out. Hope this serves somebody in the near future

Comment: use ```CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True``` if you think the above solution is not working for you

Answer (score 0):

For folks using `django-celery-email` -- it's necessary to have the following set:

```
CELERY_EMAIL_TASK_CONFIG = {
    'name': 'djcelery_email_send',
    'ignore_result': False,
}

CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_EMAIL_CHUNK_SIZE = 1
```

I believe the similar problems I was having were due to having `'ignore_result'` be set to `True`. From the `django-celery-email` docs:

> results will be a list of celery AsyncResult objects that you may
>   ignore, or use to check the status of the email delivery task, or even
>   wait for it to complete if want. You have to enable a result backend
>   and set ignore_result to False in CELERY_EMAIL_TASK_CONFIG if you want
>   to use these. You should also set CELERY_EMAIL_CHUNK_SIZE = 1 in
>   settings if you are concerned about task status and results.

Hopefully this helps other folks, similarly also spent several hours figuring this out...