# Python Celery Q Task Status Always Pending or Success

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am trying to run around Django and Celery.
I just using sample program and get stuck in Status of the Tasks. I am not sure, if I doing any wrong with configuration, but everything seems to follow all the steps. Also the Backend and Workers is working properly. In case, I want to get the status of the Q-tasks so that it's easy to identify whether the Job is "Running", "Success", or "Failure". But I end up with the status always "PENDING" and "SUCCESS" in case of Success.

Sample Sum for Worker

[image: Sample Sum for Worker]
Worker Information

[image]
Job Call

[image]

Job 1st Check Status --> Always Pending

[image]
Check Status from AsynChronization --> Also Always Pending or Success in Case of complete

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Celery 4.0 or above, the `CELERY_TRACK_STARTED` setting has been renamed to `CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED`.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49240216/1342257